# FTP upload files from Eclipse with Aptana plugin from PHP Explorer

Tags: eclipse, ftp, aptana

Is there a quick and simple way to upload php files from eclipse. In dreamweaver I would use shift-command-u. I have setup Aptana plugin and the FTP is working, however the only way I can figure out how to upload a single file is to navigate the Remote connection, find the file and then right click and select upload.

I would think there should be a upload file from the PHP or Project explorer too ?

Thanks

Comment: In the standalone Aptana Studio, the shortcut is Ctrl + Shift + U. I can't speak for Eclipse with Aptana as a plugin.

Comment: Waited too long to edit... You can assign shortcuts in your Preferences - there may be an FTP upload command listed there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried it in my Eclipse install with Aptana plugin and there is indeed an 'Upload' command that you can assign key bindings to under `Window > Preferences > General > Keys`. I had some trouble when I tried it because my `Ctrl + Shift + U` shortcut was already taken by my OS (PeppermintOS 3), but I was able to clear that by going into my Preferences > Input Method Switcher and choosing xim instead of the default. Don't know if that is relevant to your situation or not.

Comment: Thanks for the tip and it almost works, however I have to click on the file in the PHP Explorer and then Ctrl + Shift + U and it will upload. If I am working in the PHP file and hit that, nothing happens. I think it is something to do with the "when" option in keys. It is currently set to "In Windows". I am on Mac OS 10.8

Comment: Mine is also set to "In Windows" and it uploads when my cursor is in an open file - I did not try it from the file explorer. Are there any key conflicts for the key combo? They would be listed in the same place where you can set them up. You could also try an alternate key combo to see if that is the problem?